# Best way to mitigate null HTTP request in apache2

Tags: http, tomcat, networking, request, apache2

I recently had to migrate an infrastructure consisting of a load balancer and three backends. Each backend is setup with apache2 to handle HTTP/HTTPs requests and forward them through the AJP protocol to a tomcat server.

Something I don't understand appears in apache2. If I look to the server-status page, I see a bunch of [workers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html) stuck in a read state, with the request being the NULL request.
After the [Timeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html#timeout) of apache2 is reached, the worker is killed and no timeout error (408) is sent to the client, which makes sense since the client is not even making a request..

It's like the socket is not properly closed or something like that but i'm not sure. We didn't experienced this with apache2.2 and now we are using apache2.4. The connection doesn't appear in tomcat, only in apache.

This can be mitigated by a low Timeout value but I would like to know if this is something well-known from the community, with a simple solution, or if there are ways to properly solve this issue.

*Configuration*:
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu). mod_jk/1.2.43. Tomcat7. IPVS and Keepalived.

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. one way is to use mod_qos to deny half open connection by requiring a min data rate.